# apt-get update using binary-x64 instead of binary-amd64 and failing

Tags: apt

I am getting these error messages when updating my package lists.  Maybe you can help me out:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam amd64 Packages
Hit http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release [58.5 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release [58.5 kB]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [14.7 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [4,212 B]
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en_US
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources [687 B]
Ign http://repo.steampowered.com precise/steam Translation-en
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages [47.0 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages [17.7 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,154 B]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [45.1 kB]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [17.7 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages [1,404 B]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [35.9 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [23.8 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources [2,234 B]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages [83.4 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages [64.3 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7,089 B]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [81.6 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [64.5 kB]
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [7,273 B]
Fetched 639 kB in 3s (192 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I get them using my old sources.list and one I built at a repo building site mentioned from other similar questions.  See my current sources.list below.

```
###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

When viewing the failed urls, I notice that these list main/binary-amd64 instead of binary-x64.  It appears that I could fix this by putting deb=amd64 in each sources line, but I doubt that this is the root of the issue.
uname -a returns:

> Linux Knights 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>   In case it matters I did upgrade this from 13.10.

Output from dpkg --print-foreign-architectures:

```
i386
x64
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is easy to fix. Just type:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture x64
```

Now, someone added that architecture there. That's not a valid architecture. The only valid architectures are:

- amd64
- armhf
- i386
- powerpc
- ppc64el

To add any of them just use:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture <arch>
```

Where arch is one of the above.