# apt-get searching for binary-armhf with INTEL i7 CPU

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, cpu-architecture

When I run: apt-get update I receive the following errors:

Err `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main` armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe` armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main` armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe` armhf Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

Ign `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com` trusty/main Translation-en_US

Ign `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com` trusty/universe Translation-en_US

W: Failed to fetch `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-armhf/Packages`  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/universe/binary-armhf/Packages`  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages`  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: `Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-armhf/Packages`  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I cleared /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d and reverted to trusty main repos, e.g, the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list is simply:

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` trusty main universe
deb-src `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` trusty main universe

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` trusty-updates main universe
deb-src `http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` trusty-updates main universe

What triggers the package manager to look for the binary-armhf directory and how can I stop these errors when updating my packages?

Why is my distro searching for the binary-armhf directory? I'm have an intel i7 and don't believe it uses the arm instruction set, doesn't it have its own x86_64 (I could be wrong, I don't know much about cpu architecture)?

In case it is helpful, the output of cat /proc/cpuinfo for on of my cores is:

`processor  : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 44
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU       X 990  @ 3.47GHz
stepping    : 2
microcode   : 0x13
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
cache size  : 12288 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 12
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 6
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 11
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt aes lahf_lm ida arat epb dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid
bogomips    : 6941.82
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:`

Thanks for any direction, I've been struggling with this for a while.

Comment: After you reset your sources.list are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: @spk593 Possibly a duplicate of `http://askubuntu.com/questions/499986/apt-get-update-does-not-work`

Comment: @Seth Yes all the output I posted was after I reset the sources.list and sources.list.d

Comment: @vembutech I don't believe this is a duplicate. A part of the question is why is the package manager searching for /binary-armhf because I don't believe it should be in the first place. I'm also looking at the trusty repo which is the most up-to-date.

Answer (score 7):

It is likely that you have installed (for example) armhf cross tools (compiler, linker, etc.) that add `armhf` as foreign architecture. You can verify this by running:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

You can remove the foreign architecture by running:

```
sudo dpkg --force-architecture --remove-architecture armhf
```

For me, the package adding `armhf` as foreign architecure was `cuda-cross-armhf-6-5`.

Comment: What if I want the foreign architectures for cross-compilation?  How do I fix the apt error?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558847/install-armhf-lib-on-x86-via-apt-get you have to prefix your apt repo entries with the specific arch.

Comment: @kevinf:  Does your hint about the arch prefix adding also applies to Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty)? Or in other words: Where is the trusty armhf directory to be found on the Ubuntu servers?

Comment: @pefu yes it works on Trusty.. all the distributions found on a mirror can be found at this path: http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/

Comment: You saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer!

[apt-get update using binary-x64 instead of binary-amd64 and failing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/469373/apt-get-update-using-binary-x64-instead-of-binary-amd64-and-failing?rq=1)

I am still unclear as to how and why the foreign architectures are populated for the package manager but removing the armhf entry stops the search for the non-existent directory in the trusty repo.